# convenient way to take out class members to external class or trait?

Tags: java, scala, scalatest

In my TestSpec class I have bunch of properties and its starting to be crowded, something like:

```
implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  val client: WSClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
  val env: Environment = app.injector.instanceOf[Environment]
  val config: Configuration = app.configuration
  val j4s: Json4s = app.injector.instanceOf[Json4s]
  val actSys: ActorSystem = app.injector.instanceOf[ActorSystem]
  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer

  // mocking service
  val myService: ChironApiService = mock[MyService]

  val rawTextModel: String =
    """{"message":"a message","reason":"Done","list":[34,2,12]}"""
  val badResponseModel: ModelOne = JsonMethods.parse(rawTextModel).extract[BadResModel]

  val futureOfEither: Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future(Left("fr"))
.
.
.
```

so I thought taking it out to a trait and add this trait to TestSpec and then I can access the info, is there a more elegant scala way to do something like this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
trait TestConfig {
    val client: WSClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
    val env: Environment = app.injector.instanceOf[Environment]
    val config: Configuration = app.configuration
    val j4s: Json4s = app.injector.instanceOf[Json4s]
    val actSys: ActorSystem = app.injector.instanceOf[ActorSystem]
    implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer
 }

 class TestSpec extends TestConfig {
    // mocking service
    val myService: ChironApiService = mock[MyService]

    val rawTextModel: String =
        """{"message":"a message","reason":"Done","list":[34,2,12]}"""
    val badResponseModel: ModelOne = JsonMethods.parse(rawTextModel).extract[BadResModel]

    val futureOfEither: Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future(Left("fr"))
    .
    .
    .
 }
```